# what is anchor #[instruction()] macro?

Tags: anchor, account

I have this code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(campaign_id: u32)]
pub struct CreateCompaign<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [SEED.as_bytes(), &compaign_id.to_le_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub campaign: Account<'info, Campaign>,
   // ....
}
```

what is this `#[instruction(campaign_id: u32)]` how does it work? I googled it, and searched it on this platform but could not see anything. (I called it as macro but I am not sure if it is a macro)

Answer (score 2):

It is a macro, and it lets you access your instruction arguments in your validator(i.e `Accounts` struct). Here for instance, without the instruction macro, you wouldn't be able to write the check for the `campaign` pda's seeds.

So here the `#[instruction(campaign_id: u32)]` line says "Get the value from the instruction arguments for use in the validator". That way the check for the 2nd seed of `campaign` is bound to your instruction argument

Comment: the problem is there is no instruction on the front-end

Comment: what do you mean by that? There isn't any method with a ctx of `Context<CreateCampaign>` in your anchor program module?

Comment: if you have `#[instruction(campaign_id: u32)]` in your program, you are telling it that your instruction with `Context<CreateCampaign>` should also have a `campaign_id` passed. your `Campaign` PDA is seeded with this id, so it's necessary to pass from the front end.

Comment: In case you want to poke around the macro definition, you can find it at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/syn/src/codegen/program/instruction.rs